# TFloatAnimation to fade out a pricture not working together with a TMonochromeEffect

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

For a Delphi 10.2 Firemonkey Windows application I would like to apply a `TMonochromeEffect` and multiple other effects to a picture. I use `TLayout` containers as described here: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_FireMonkey_Image_Effects#Applying_Multiple_Effects_to_a_Picture

At the same time I would like to use a `TFloatAnmination` to fade out the picture.

The fade out animation does not work if the `TMonochromeEffect` is enabled.

Here is a small example application (using only one `TMonochromeEffect`) which shows the problem:

[image]

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Objects, FMX.Ani, FMX.Effects,
  FMX.Filter.Effects, FMX.Layouts;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    FloatAnimation1: TFloatAnimation;
    MonochromeEffect1: TMonochromeEffect;
    Layout1: TLayout;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('D:\MyPicture.jpg');
end;


procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FloatAnimation1.Enabled:=false;
  FloatAnimation1.StopValue:=0;
  FloatAnimation1.Enabled:=true;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //MonochromeEffect1.Enabled:=false; //works fine
  MonochromeEffect1.Enabled:=true; //not working
end;

end.
```

and

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Layout1: TLayout
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object Image1: TImage
      MultiResBitmap = <
        item
        end>
      Align = Client
      Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      object FloatAnimation1: TFloatAnimation
        Duration = 2.000000000000000000
        PropertyName = 'Opacity'
        StartValue = 0.000000000000000000
        StartFromCurrent = True
        StopValue = 0.000000000000000000
      end
    end
    object MonochromeEffect1: TMonochromeEffect
      Enabled = False
    end
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Position.X = 12.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 12.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 120.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 69.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 1
    object Button1: TButton
      Position.X = 20.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'load image'
      OnClick = Button1Click
    end
    object Button2: TButton
      Position.X = 20.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 32.000000000000000000
      TabOrder = 1
      Text = 'fade out'
      OnClick = Button2Click
    end
  end
end
```

Clicking on `Button1` loads the picture.

Clicking on `Button2` fades out the picture.

The `FloatAnimation1` is acting on the opacity of the `Image1`.

The `MonoChromeEffect1` is applied on `Layout1` (as suggested in https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_FireMonkey_Image_Effects#Applying_Multiple_Effects_to_a_Picture)

Fading out is working when the `MonoChromeEffect1` is disabled. Is does not work when the `MonoChromeEffect1` is enabled.

Any suggestions what could be the problem?

**Addendum 1:**

If I add an `FloatAnimation1.OnProcess` event handler which repaints `Layout1` it works also when the `MonoChromeEffect1` is enabled.

```
procedure TForm1.FloatAnimation1Process(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Layout1.Repaint;
end;
```

**Addendum 2:**

If I add an `FloatAnimation1.OnProcess` event handler which calls `Layout1.UpdateEffects` it works as well when the `MonoChromeEffect1` is enabled.

```
procedure TForm1.FloatAnimation1Process(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Layout1.UpdateEffects;
end;
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Use Animation.Start instead. IMHO there is no need of a Layout

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FloatAnimation1.Start:=true;
end;
```

[image: Structure]